# How to make a png file a button in html

Tags: html, png

I'm not a programmer by trade, but I'm trying to turn a PNG file into a button in html but im having trouble getting the button to be flush with the png in a way that doesn't look bad.  I've googled many solutions so far but either i don't have the understanding to implement the fixes or my problems isn't what i think it is.

```html
<a href="file:///E:/eLibrary_Jamaica_2019/Please_Click_Me_For_eLibrary.html">
  <button type="submit" style="height:80px; width:360px "><img src="../../Web/media/images/FULLLOGOENACTUS 2.png" width="360" height="80" alt="" padding-right="50px" syle="content-align:center" 
    alt="Submit">
  </button>
</a>
```

[This is what the current code produces.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FL1h.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following CSS to the code:

```
button {
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

This fits the png within the button and removes the button padding (buttons have padding unless you remove it). You could also add this to your inline html:

```
<a href="file:///E:/eLibrary_Jamaica_2019/Please_Click_Me_For_eLibrary.html">
  <button type="submit" style="height:80px; width:360px; padding: 0"><img src="../../Web/media/images/FULLLOGOENACTUS 2.png" width="360" height="80" alt="" padding-right="50px" syle="content-align:center; width: 100%; height: 100%" 
    alt="Submit">
  </button>
</a>
```

Side note.. you shouldn't wrap buttons in a tags. this is bad for seo, accessibility, and many other things.. Just wrapping your image in an a tag and styling accordingly will do what you're looking for whilst being compliant. A button isn't needed unless you're trying to submit a form of some sort -- and even in that case, don't wrap the button in an a tag

Comment: So do i have to add the CSS to the amended html portion? I used the modified html code you shared and it still looks the same.

Comment: Odd, that worked for me to just use the modified html code: 
```
<a href="file:///E:/eLibrary_Jamaica_2019/Please_Click_Me_For_eLibrary.html">
  <button type="submit" style="height:80px; width:360px; padding: 0"><img src="../../Web/media/images/FULLLOGOENACTUS 2.png" width="360" height="80" alt="" padding-right="50px" syle="content-align:center; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: contain; " 
    alt="Submit">
  </button>
</a>
``` Would this work?

Comment: It didn't.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class on your button and style it from within the style sheet using background.

```
<input type="button" class="button" ...>
```

then in your style sheet

```
.button
{
    background: url(path/to/img.png) no-repeat ...;
    cursor: pointer;
    ....
}
```

It is just always a good idea to separate your markup from your styles. I would also suggest that whatever the button actually does (unless it is just a link to something else), use javascript for that.